# FluentValidation asynchronous rule is hanging

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asynchronous, fluentvalidation

I use Fluent Validate and I want to check if chosen parameter can be used. Checking is provided by database so I want my RuleFor to be async. I wrote it and in some article I read that one must call validation via ValidateAsync in order not to have it hanged. So I added code that calls this ValidateAsync

```
[Route("create/single")]
[HttpPost]
[ResponseType(typeof(Invoice))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(Invoice entity)
{
    var validator = _validatorFactory.GetValidator<InvoiceBillToActivityValidation>();
    var validationResult = await validator.ValidateAsync(entity);
    var modelState = validationResult.ToModelState();
    if (!validationResult.IsValid)
        return BadRequest(modelState);
    return await Post<AddEntityUseCase<Invoice, int>>(entity);
}
```

The problem is that when request begins somewhy it comes to the validator around my Post method and I assume calls the Validate method so the request hangs.

Is there some kind of feature of the fluent validate to call validator by default for the class that it has been created? Then how to turn it off or how to set it to call the ValidateAsync method?